# laravel png 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: html

i get this error 403 (Forbidden) in png image in laravel project
this is my image code

```
<img src="/images/logo/black.png" alt="logo" style="max-width: 40px; max-height:40px;"
                        class="img-responsive" />
```

this error just show in png image and jpg image is work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php or laravel. Check the permissions of the file on the server. I think it's missing reading rights for the webserver user.

Comment: Thank you that is right it was a problem in permissions

Answer (score 0):

Error code **403** means `Forbidden`. This means, that you are not authorized to read the requested resource. Check your file permission and the user rights.

You can [read more about the 403 error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) at mozilla website.

Answer (score 0):

1st.Error Code 403 Means Forbidden. check your permissions of your server as well as check .htaccess file permissions

2nd. You does not want to write hardcoded(manually) full path. you can access any file like below ways...

for access any type of file, asset files(CSS, Js etc) or image from **Public Path**

> {{ asset('images/logo/black.png') }}

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo/black.png') }}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

& if you put image at **Storage Path**, then first you need to **link storage with public**

you need to run below CMD command for link storage with public

> php artisan storage:link

then for access image for example assume your image located in storage/app/public/myfolder then you can display it like below

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app/myfolder/myimage.jpg') }}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<!------ OR ------>
<img src="{{ asset("storage/app/myfolder/myimage.jpg") }}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: It was a problem in permissions. Thank you

Comment: yes brother I know, but I shared extra useful tips. I hope this helps to you

Comment: & accept corect answer from all answers which one helps to you better. So other people can identify easily